# React component not re-rendering on state change with connect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating a todo app where TodoApp is the main Component which contain filterLink a simple link and a VisibleTodoList section, whenever I toggle the todolist it changes its state and re render the filter component which is not using connect but VisibleTodoList(which is using connect) is not re render

```
class TodoApp extends Component {  
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input ref={node =>{
          this.input=node;
        }}/>
        <button onClick={
            ()=>{
                store.dispatch(actions.addTodo(count++,this.input.value));
            }
        }>Add Todo</button>
      <FilterLink filter='SHOW_ALL' store={store.getState()}/>
      <FilterLink filter='ACTIVE' store={store.getState()}/>
      <FilterLink filter='COMPLETED' store={store.getState()}/>

      <VisibleTodoList/>     

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

VisibleTodoList contain

```
 const getVisibleTodos= (visible,todo)=>{

    switch(visible){
      case 'ACTIVE':

return todo.filter((item)=>item.completed === false)
case 'COMPLETED':
return todo.filter((item) => item.completed === true);
default :
return todo;
    }

}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
   todo: getVisibleTodos(state.visiblity,state.todo)
})

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
  return {
    onTodoClick:(id)=>{
 dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id));
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

TodoItem contain

```
  class TodoItem extends Component {


          render(){
            return(

                 <ul>
                {this.props.todo.map((item)=> 
                  <TodoList key={item.id} {...item} onTodoClick={this.props.onTodoClick}
                  />   
                )}
                </ul>
            );
        }
        }


        TodoList contain

        class TodoList extends Component {

          render(){
            console.log(this.props)
              const {id,text,completed,onTodoClick} =this.props;
            return (
             <li
                  style={{textDecoration:completed?'line-through':''}}
                  onClick={()=>onTodoClick(id)}>{text}</li> 
            )
          }
        }
```

The combine reducer contain todo and visiblity reducer

```
function visible(state='SHOW_ALL',action){
    switch(action.type){

case 'VISIBLITY_FILTER':return action.filter;

default:return state;
    }


}
```

index.js(reducer)

```
function todo(state=[],action){
switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    return[
        ...state,{
            id:action.id,
            text:action.text,
            completed:false
        }
    ];

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':

    let t=  state.map(item =>{
        if(item.id === action.id){
            item.completed =!item.completed;
        }
    });
    return state;

    default: {
        return state;
}
}
}

const todos=combineReducers({
    todo,
    visiblity
})
```

This is the corresponding action creator which is imported as actions

```
export const toggleTodo=(id)=>{
   return{
             type:'TOGGLE_TODO',
             id:id

            }
}

export const addTodo=(count,val)=>{
    return {
                    id:count,
                    text:val,
                    type:'ADD_TODO'
                }
}
```

Comment: Why is your TodoList rendering an HTML list-item and your TodoItem rendering an HTML unordered-list? Your naming is backwards.

Comment: ya that I have to change but the major problem is here the component not rerendering the visibleTodolist

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: It might be the case that your state's change doesn't get through. React is only doing a shallow comparison to find out whether or not it should re-render. This might be your problem if your state is just regular javascript objects of which you edit some properties. You might want to include some code regarding your reducers as well.

Comment: I think it might be useful if you posted what your action/reducer is actually doing. From your current code posted, we can only derive that `actions.addTodo()` is being dispatched, but cannot determine what this action does to affect the state and if it actually creates a new visibile todo item

Comment: I have added the correspondng action-creators and reducers for it